# Can we ADD an EXCLUSION SCRIPT to an existing EmailActivity in a running Journey via API [how to expire an email]

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, exclusion-script

- I am aware that adding exclusion scripts excluded respective Email from being excluded.
- I have an other team, who wish to control which emails to be excluded from journey.
- Are there any REST or SOAP APIs in SFMC which can be used to **ADD an Exclusion script?** to an existing email activity.

Comment: Have you thought of using an auto suppression list?

Comment: Hi @EazyE thanks for the suggestion... but requirement is NOT to exclude particular Subscribers... Instead, I don't wish to send that particular EMAIL to any one.... a kind of EXPIRING the email.

Comment: @VishalKumarCV - do you simply want to stop certain emails in the journey from sending? Does the team in question not have access to Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

The actual requirement was to EXPIRE certain emails in SFMC.
Once they are marked as EXPIRED, those emails would STOP sent out from any way [SendFlow, Automation, JB etc]

So we came up with below approach,

- Create an DE [with field 'EmailName'] to store the Names of the Email which you wish to EXPIRE.
- Place this exclusion script in every Email send activity.

`RowCount(LookUpRows("ExpiredEmails", "EmailName", emailname_)) > 0`

Note: Though the email get excluded, the contacts would still injected to journey. And only the Emails would NOT be sent.